# Warum werden „winzig“ und „unendlich“ hier nicht dekliniert?

Tags: declension

Warum werden „winzig“ und „unendlich“ im Folgenden nicht dekliniert?

> ein **winzig** kleines Körnchen in einer **unendlich** großen Sternenwolke aus
>   Milliarden von Sternen, der Milchstraße

Warum ist es nicht „[winziges](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/winzig:A)“ und „[unendlichen](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/unendlich:A)“?

Comment: What else would you expect and why? Elaborate in your question please.

Comment: (winziges)[http://www.canoo.net/inflection/winzig:A] and (unendlichen)[http://www.canoo.net/inflection/unendlich:A]

Comment: [Edit] your question citing those references please.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ There's no book called  Die unendlich Geschichte is there? I think the question is obvious and the sentence is off but ok.

Comment: No, there's nothing _seltsam_ with that sentence. It's clear and well understandable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*winzig* and *unendlich* are adverbs here; they modify the adjectives *kleines* resp. *großen*, instead of the nouns *Körnchen* and *Sternenwolke*. Unlike adjectives, adverbs are not inflected.

Comment: I agree. If English is your native language, the adverb-modifying-adjective structure is even clearer: eg. an extremely small grain or: an infinitely large star cloud.